# Changing a class attribute within __init__

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

I was looking at the Stack Overflow question [Counting instances of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628123/counting-instances-of-a-class), and I'm not sure why that solution works and one using simple addition doesn't.  I guess this is more of a question of how class vs. instance variables are stored and accessed.

Here's the code I think should work, but instead produces `4` for every `id`:

```
class foo():
      num = 3    # trying 3 instead of 0 or 1 to make sure the add is working

      def __init__(self):
        self.num += 1
        self.id = self.num

f = foo()
g = foo()

print f.id    # 4
print g.id    # 4
```

The `self.num +=1` statement is somewhat working (the addition is happening, but not the assignment).

What is happening under the hood that's making this assignment fail here, while the `itertools.count` assignment succeeds in the other question's solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self.num += 1` means, basically, 'take the value of `self.num`, increment it, and assign to `self.num`.

Looking up an attribute on `self` will find the class variable if there is no corresponding instance variable. However, *assigning* will always write to an instance variable. So, this tries to find an instance var, fails, falls back to a class var, gets the value, increments it, then assigns *to an instance var*.

The reason the answer to the linked question works is because there is no assigning going on; they call `next()` directly on the class variable, its value is mutated but the name is not reassigned.

Answer (score 7):

Integers don't implement `__iadd__` (in-place add, for `+=`), as they're immutable. The interpreter falls back to standard assignment and `__add__` instead, so the line:

```
self.num += 1
```

becomes:

```
self.num = self.num + 1
```

On the right-hand side you get `foo.num` (i.e. `3`) via `self.num`, as you expected, but the interesting thing here is that *assigning to the instance attribute `num` **shadows** the class attribute*. So the line is actually equivalent to:

```
self.num = foo.num + 1  # instance attribute equals class attribute plus one
```

All *instances* end up with `self.num == 4` and the *class* remains `foo.num == 3`. Instead, I suspect what you wanted is:

```
foo.num += 1  # explicitly update the class attribute
```

---

Alternatively, you could implement it as a `@classmethod`, working on the class more explicitly:

```
class Foo():  # note naming convention

    num = 3

    def __init__(self):
        self.increment()
        self.id = self.num  # now you're still accessing the class attribute

    @classmethod
    def increment(cls):
        cls.num += 1
```

Comment: Alternatively, `self.__class__.num += 1`

Comment: @robert that would work, but I find it a little awkward

Answer (score 2):

Augmented assignment does not update the class variable. It does this:

```
tmp = self.num
self.num = tmp.__iadd__(1)
```

Note the assignment back to `self.num` there! As such your class attribute remains untouched. The [`object.__iadd__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) for integers cannot alter the number in-place because integers are immutable, so `foo.num` never changes.

You need to explicitly reference the class variable:

```
foo.num += 1
```

or

```
self.__class__.num += 1
```