# Write a program for count the Number of objects present within the class without using Constructors

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Someone help me with logic for writing program for count the number of objects present within class without using the constructors.

Comment: I think you can find what you need here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628123/counting-instances-of-a-class

Comment: There they're using __init__ method. Without using the __init__ method I need the logic

Comment: Why do you need to count the number of objects without using constructors? Because you can just create a fonction  which create the object and count it. But it's a little "weird".

Comment: You can also store you're object in a list and get the length to know the number

Comment: I attended one interview and they asked to write the program without using Constructors to count the number objects present within the class. I don't know how iterate it in loop. That's why I'm asking here......

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fonction but I maintain it's a little weird:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def createAndCount(name_object, counter):
    counter+=1
    return [test(name_object), counter]

counter = 0
p1, counter = createAndCount("Ronflex", counter)
p2, counter = createAndCount("Doudou", counter)
```